# Custom agenda view for tasks without dates and with/ without specific tag

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda, time-date

I can have a custom agenda view that shows all tasks without a date with a custom agenda view defined thus:

```
'(org-agenda-custom-commands
   (quote
    (("d" "Undated tasks" alltodo ""
      ((org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date t))))))
```

I want to refine this further based on tags. So, say, I need to have a custom agenda view of tasks without date and with a tagA. Or I need to have another custom agenda view of tasks without date but without a tagB. Or I need to have yet another custom agenda view of tasks without date and with tagA but without tagB.

How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've used in the past:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("d" "Undated tasks" tags-todo "tagA"
         ((org-agenda-skip-function '(org-agenda-skip-entry-if
                          'deadline 'scheduled 'timestamp))))))
```

I also got your example to work with a few tweaks:

```lisp
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("d" "Undated tasks" tags-todo "tagA"
         ((org-agenda-tags-todo-honor-ignore-options t)
          (org-agenda-todo-ignore-with-date t)))))
```

Edit. The above shows you all undated tasks tagged with tagA. It looks like you want all undated tasks as well as tagA (even if tagA has a date). In this case you need:

```lisp
(defun skip-dated-tasks (&optional tag)
  (save-restriction
    (save-excursion
      (org-narrow-to-subtree)
      (if (or (null (org-get-scheduled-time (point)))
              (and tag (member tag (org-get-tags))))
          nil
        (or (outline-next-heading) (point-max))))))

(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
      '(("d" "Undated tasks" alltodo ""
         ((org-agenda-skip-function (lambda () (skip-dated-tasks "tagA")))))))
```